# JSON.parse appending empty array to end of string argument

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm writing a simple Node.JS app that works with the GitHub API to pull user statistics. I'm sending a GET request to `/repos/:user/:repo_name/stats/contributors` which should return to me a JSON string. Here's my function:

```
function getRepoCommits(token,repos,user,callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<repos.length; i++) {
        var returnChunk = '';
        var full_name = repos[i].full_name;
        //console.log(full_name);
        var options = {
            host: 'api.github.com',
            path: '/repos/'+full_name+'/stats/contributors',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'token '+token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
        };

        var request = https.request(options, function(res) {
            //res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                returnChunk += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function(chunk) {
                console.log(returnChunk);
                var stats = JSON.parse(returnChunk);
                console.log(stats.length);
                for (var j=0;j<stats.length;j++) {
                }
                if (i == repos.length-1) {
                    //callback();
                }
            })
        });

        request.on('error',function(err) {
            callback(err);
            console.log(err);
        });
        request.end();
    }
}
```

The area of interest is right here:

```
            res.on('end', function(chunk) {
                console.log(returnChunk);
                var stats = JSON.parse(returnChunk);
                console.log(stats.length);
                for (var j=0;j<stats.length;j++) {
                }
                if (i == repos.length-1) {
                    //callback();
                }
            })
```

When I check the value of `returnChunk`, it is a valid JSON string in the format :

```
[{json}]
```

However, when the function reaches `JSON.parse`, it throws an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Basically, it's appending an extra `[]` to the end of the string before parsing it. It becomes

```
[{json}][]
```

I've tried for hours on end to figure out how to deal with this problem, but I can't seem to figure out why it is doing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean it's appending the `[]` to the end? Where do you see that in your logging?

Comment: I see what's happening. You're making several asynchronous requests in a loop, and having them all append to the same `returnChunk` variable, so all your data is getting mixed together. Remember, JavaScript doesn't have block scope, only function scope, so it's as if you put `var returnChunk = ""` at the top of the function.

Comment: @BlueSkies - you should post that as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making several asynchronous requests in a loop, and having them all append to the same `returnChunk` variable, so all your data is getting mixed together.

Remember, JavaScript doesn't have block scope, only function scope, so it's as if you put `var returnChunk = ""` at the top of the function.

A solution would be to use `.forEach()` instead of a `for` statement so that  the callback will give you a new scope for each iteration.

```
repos.forEach(function(repo, i) {
    var returnChunk = '';
    var full_name = repo.full_name;
    //console.log(full_name);
    var options = {
        host: 'api.github.com',
        path: '/repos/'+full_name+'/stats/contributors',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'token '+token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    };

    var request = https.request(options, function(res) {
        //res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            returnChunk += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(chunk) {
            console.log(returnChunk);
            var stats = JSON.parse(returnChunk);
            console.log(stats.length);
            for (var j=0;j<stats.length;j++) {
            }

// !!! This will be unreliable because you don't know which one will finish last.
//     You could maintain a separate counter that is incremented as each "end" fires
//        to make sure the `callback()` happens on the last one.
            if (i == repos.length-1) {
                //callback();
            }
        })
    });

    request.on('error',function(err) {
        callback(err);
        console.log(err);
    });
    request.end();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It worked perfectly. It was one of those d'oh moments that just goes to show how much I have to learn! I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep points yet!